# Create new variable by finding date and correct decile in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

this issue in R is driving me nuts since one week so I would be really happy about any help: I have 1 big data frame with ca. 100.000 valuation ratios for stocks where I would like to assign every stock every year to one of 10 portfolios by creating a new variable "BM_Portfolio" based on deciles I have calculated for every year in a second dataframe called BP.

This is the 1. dataframe "CCM2_June_all_stocks" with all valuation ratios:

**Date;  stock;     BE_ME**
2011-06-30; TELENAV INC; 0.38
2012-06-30; TELENAV INC; 0.30
2013-06-30; TELENAV INC; 0.56

This is the 2. dataframe "BP" with the deciles (=breakpoints) per year:
**Date; BE_ME_10%; BE_ME.20%; BE_ME.30%; BE_ME.40%; BE_ME.50%; etc**
2011-06-30; TELENAV INC; 0.20; 0.29; 0.37; 0.44; 0.53 etc
2012-06-30; TELENAV INC; 0.22; 0.27; 0.36; 0.45; 0.55 etc
2013-06-30; TELENAV INC; 0.24; 0.30; 0.34; 0.46; 0.57 etc

My code assigns every stock to a portfolio but sometimes the portfolio number is wrong by -1 or +1:

```
CCM2_June_all_stocks$BM_Portfolio <- ifelse(CCM2_June_all_stocks$Date %in% BP$Date & CCM2_June_all_stocks$BE_ME_Dec <= BP$X10., 1,
                          ifelse(CCM2_June_all_stocks$Date %in% BP$Date & CCM2_June_all_stocks$BE_ME_Dec <= BP$X20., 2,
                          ifelse(CCM2_June_all_stocks$Date %in% BP$Date & CCM2_June_all_stocks$BE_ME_Dec <= BP$X30., 3,
                          ifelse(CCM2_June_all_stocks$Date %in% BP$Date & CCM2_June_all_stocks$BE_ME_Dec <= BP$X40., 4,
                          ifelse(CCM2_June_all_stocks$Date %in% BP$Date & CCM2_June_all_stocks$BE_ME_Dec <= BP$X50., 5,
                          ifelse(CCM2_June_all_stocks$Date %in% BP$Date & CCM2_June_all_stocks$BE_ME_Dec <= BP$X60., 6,
                          ifelse(CCM2_June_all_stocks$Date %in% BP$Date & CCM2_June_all_stocks$BE_ME_Dec <= BP$X70., 7,
                          ifelse(CCM2_June_all_stocks$Date %in% BP$Date & CCM2_June_all_stocks$BE_ME_Dec <= BP$X80., 8,
                          ifelse(CCM2_June_all_stocks$Date %in% BP$Date & CCM2_June_all_stocks$BE_ME_Dec <= BP$X90., 9, 10)))))))))
```

In addition, I get 9 warning messages, so I assume there are more reliable ways to code this:

```
Warning messages:
1: In CCM2_June_all_stocks$BE_ME_Dec <= BP$X10. :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Any idea how I can solve this? The solution should be:
**Date;  stock;     BE_ME; BM_Portfolio**
2011-06-30; TELENAV INC; 0.38; **4** (as it is smaller than 0.44)
2012-06-30; TELENAV INC; 0.30; **3** (as it is smaller than 0.36)
2013-06-30; TELENAV INC; 0.56; **5** (as it is smaller than 0.57)

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
BM_Merged <- merge(CCM2_June_all_stocks, BP, by=c("Date", "stock"))
Portfolio <- apply(BM_Merged, 1, function(x)match(TRUE, x[3] <= x[-(1:3)]))
BM_Result <- cbind(BM_Merged[, 1:3], BM_Portfolio=Portfolio)
```

If you have to create some unwieldy repetitive structure like your nest of of ifelses, it is a bit of clue that there is a simpler way to do it.

Comment: Thanks Knackiedoo. `merge` doesn't work here as both dataframes are very different: The large dataframe "CCM2_June_all_stocks" has more than 100.000 rows with a B/M ratio for stock xyz. The small dataframe "BP" has only 30 rows (for 30 years from 1985-2015) and 10 columns with the decile boundaries for the B/M ratios for every year. <br> So I think the workflow should be something like 1. for every date in the large dataframe find the row with the same date in the dataframe "BP", 2. check in which BM-decile the BM ratio fits in, 3. assign the Portfolio number 1-10 based on the decile.Any idea?

Comment: Point 1 is exactly what the merge does.  What happens when you try it?  I thought you might have multiple stocks in one or other file, so it matches those too.  If you want to ignore stock, then just omit that from the merge.  If you can dput some of the data (not all 100,000 rows obviously!) then that would help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts. A colleague of mine was able to solve this with 2 loops:

Comment: `CCM_DT = data.table(CCM2_June_all_stocks)`
`CCM_DT[, YEAR := year(Date)]`
`BP_DT = data.table(BP)`
`BP_DT[, YEAR := year(Date)]`
`years = BP_DT[, YEAR]`
`CCM_DT[, DEC := 0]`
`setkey(CCM_DT, YEAR, BE_ME_Dec)`
`setkey(BP_DT, YEAR)`
for (i in 1:length(years)) {
  for (j in 1:10) {
    if (j == 1) {
      CCM_DT[YEAR == years[i] & BE_ME_Dec <= as.numeric(BP_DT[i, j+1, with = F]), DEC := j]
    } else {
      CCM_DT[YEAR == years[i] & BE_ME_Dec <= as.numeric(BP_DT[i, j+1, with = F]) & BE_ME_Dec > as.numeric(BP_DT[i, j, with = F]), DEC := j]
    }
  }
}
CCM_DT[DEC == 0, DEC := 10]`